# setuptools compiled C extension name

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to package my python project with setuptools, and in my project I used ctypes to wrap several C files and I have the following instruction in setup.py, however, when I run it, the file it produced is not c.so under a/b, instead it is a/b/c.cpython-34m.so, how should I use it in my project? (everyone uses different versions of python, I cannot generate all possible names)

```
extensions.append(Extension(
    "a.b.c",
    glob("a/b/src/*.c"),
    include_dirs = ["a/b/src/h/"],
    language = "c"
    ))
```